# A question about modals

Tags: will-would

What is the difference in meaning between:

> Would the boss cancel the meeting?

> Will the boss cancel the meeting?

When should one use first, and when second?

Comment: What do you think the difference is? Can you give us an example of when you would use each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we had a big snowstorm, would the boss cancel the meeting?

We had 30cm of snow. (In US would be a foot, ech!)
Will the boss cancel the meeting?

Would is speculative. WIll is a prediction or intent.